# TypeScript failed to detect Null Pointer Error

Tags: typescript

I enabled the `strictNullChecks` option, and TypeScript will detect null pointer errors:

```
class A { hi(){} }
let a: A
a.hi() // => Error correctly detected
```

But if I change it a little, the TypeScript won't be able to detect it:

```
class A { hi(){} }
let a: A
function b() { a.hi() } // => Failed to detect error
```

Is it known issue or maybe there's some other TS option I need to enable to catch such errors?